# Error trying to connect to business network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I have created a peer admin card. Installed the business network successfully. Trying to start a business network using :

```
composer network start --networkName  procurement-phase --networkVersion 0.0.87 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
```

**The result of execution:**

> Starting business network procurement-phase at version 0.0.87
>
> Processing these Network Admins:
>           userName: admin
>
> ✖ Starting a business network definition. This may take a minute...
>   *Error: Error trying to start a business network. Error: Failed to receive commit notification from 192.168.1.164:9051 for transaction
>   '02339b7d2f056310c6659430e51e6dd2c99f6ecfbc094b7696ab14fc726716b5'
>   within the timeout period Command failed*

If i execute the same command again and I got another error like :

> *Starting business network definition. This may take a minute... Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: Peer
>   localhost:7051 has rejected transaction
>   '9704b94187a74aaa6d190441326edff60d675ef377607f91f69d333d6c70749a'
>   with code ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE* Command failed.

I have checked docker logs of containers running. Got an error in an orderer docker container .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the above problem by making the following changes :
Add the **tls**(**server.key-private key file ,ca.crt file,server.crt file**) of orderer in **enviroment** variables of **orderer** section in **docker-compose.yaml** file .

```
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLSENABLED=true
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.key
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt
```

Add the below section in **volumes** of  **peers** section of **docker-compose.yaml** file.Specify the path of tls folder

```
 ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/peer/tls
```